# Как в wordpress сделать блок видимый только для зарегистрированных пользователей?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть строчка в магазине wordpress woocommerce. `<p>Скидка.......<b>5%</b><br></p>` 
Как ее сделать видимой только для зарегистрированных пользователей?

Answer (score 1):

google не, не слышал, и ещё что было 30 символов

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ... } ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

Comment: ок, а как тогда строчку `<p>Скидка.......<b>5%</b><br></p>` вывести в определенном месте?

Comment: <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo '<p>Скидка.......<b>5%</b><br></p>'} ?> посмотрите как в пхп выводить html, но примерно как то так

Comment: да, но он ведь лишь бы куда выведет, а не туда, куда мне нужно - правда?)

Comment: правда))) для того что бф он вывел куда нужно его нужно вставить куда нужно, вам куда нужно?

Comment: ну, скажем  в низ сплывающей корзины

Comment: woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php где то там, откройте пож-та гугл